# Dynamic WHERE with variable number of conditions from parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query similar to this example which I'd like to turn into a stored proc, rather than building/passing dynamically. I can't use a simpler query with an IN because I need to match pairs of columns...

eg

```
select [col1] from [table]
where ( ([col2] = 'A' and [col3] = '1')
     or ([col2] = 'B' and [col3] = '2')
     or ([col2] = 'C' and [col3] = '3') )
```

the number of pairs of [col2], [col3] tests will be varied.

I had tried passing the parameter as a string like `A|1,B|2,C|3` and then using `string_split(@param,',')` to get the pairs and use the result in a cursor to go through the results, splitting each in turn on the | to build my `where` clause string, but, running into problems on the second `split_string` ... didn't get much further.

A possible solution will be because I know there's a limit of 9 pairs (in current version of the system) I could pass 9 parameters and build that way, or I could manually construct the 1..9 sets of `or`s and pass as a single parameter - hopefully there is a more elegant (and performant) solution

One other limitation to note, this server is compat level 130 and won't be upgraded for a while

Comment: Table valued parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a table-valued parameter or JSON. Below is a JSON example, which unlike a TVP, does not require creating a table type beforehand.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX) = N'
[
    {"col2":"A", "col3":"1"},
    {"col2":"B", "col3":"2"},
    {"col2":"C", "col3":"3"}
]';

select col1 
from [table] AS t
JOIN OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH (
     col2 char(1)
    ,col3 int
)
AS parms ON
    parms.col2= t.col2
    AND parms.col3= t.col3;
```